# PL/SQL Oracle - Selecting from internal table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

**EDITED**

I have a problem with performing some PL/SQL code.
I have real table `a`. I want to take only elements with `range<=100`. I make a collection inside my PL/SQL based on that table. Then I want to perform `SELECT` operation on that collection. But I got a problem with it.

Prepared table (this is all for example, it's not a real problem. I just would like to know how can I select from collection in PL/SQL code block).

```
CREATE TABLE a (amount NUMBER);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (50);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (100);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (200);
```

And then I got this block:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE aTable IS TABLE OF a%ROWTYPE;
  aActual aTable;
  temp NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO aActual 
    FROM a WHERE amount<=100;

    SELECT SUM(amount) INTO temp FROM TABLE(aActual);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(temp);
END;
```

But I got eroor `PLS-00642` and `ORA-22905`.
What can I do? Why it doesn't work that way?
I'm on `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production` version (according to `SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;`)

Comment: If you don't need the aActual table for anything else, don't use it.  Just select the sum of the range from the Kocury table.

Comment: @DanBracuk I know, but I do need this table. Here I only presented small amount of code to explain what problem I get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it because `aTable` is not a database table. (Yes I know it's defined with `table of` but that doesn't define a table. One of those things.)

To ask SQL to *treat* a collection as a database table you would use the `table()` construction:

```
select sum(amount) into temp from table(aActual);
```

although this will fail in your example due to scoping issues and you'll get the self-explanatory

```
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
```

For it to work, you'd need a schema-level type i.e. one created with `create type`:

```
create or replace type xyz as object (a integer, b varchar2(3), c date);

create or replace type xyz_tt as table of xyz;
```

Now type `xyz_tt` is in effect published to SQL and it can be used in SQL `table()` expressions.

Comment: Yes, you know what I mean :)
But when I did it that way I got ORA-22905 error instead of PLS-00642. How can I fix it?

Comment: btw, there's no such thing as an 'internal table' and `table of` in PL/SQL actually defines a collection. From a PL/SQL perspective Oracle could have used a more self-explanatory keyword like `array` (as in Ada) or `collection`, but they also needed the syntax to refer to [nested table columns](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NESTED_TABLE) in database tables.

Comment: Well, I actually got both messages in my error stack when I tested it with a local collection type. Add it to your question and I'll have a look.

Comment: Updated answer with an example of what I meant by 'created with `create type`'.

Answer (score 0):

As WilliamRobertson showed, you can't use a PL/SQL collection in a SQL query. You can loop over the collection and add each amount to your temp variable, initialising it to zero first:

```
temp := 0;
for i in 1..aActual.count loop
  temp := temp + aActual(i).amount;
end loop;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(temp);
```

Comment: You can use PL/SQL collections in SQL queries in Oracle 12.1 an later.

Comment: Yes, I meant to mention that. From the errors I don't think the OP is on 12c though.

Comment: It says I'm on Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 version. I've updated my question